# how to decrypt a string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, base64

I know how to encrypt the test but I don't know how to decrypt it.

Can any one please say me how can I do it.

The code I am using to encrypt the string is

```
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("USERNAME"));
string decript = Convert.ToString(encoded);
Decrypt(encoded);
```

I don't know how to decrypt.

Comment: Pedanticism: this isn't encryption and decryption, this is encoding and decoding.

Comment: There is no encryption in your example, only encoding.

Comment: The corollary is if you're relying on base64 encoding to keep the username a secret, your whole approach is wrong.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(encoded)` is a no-op, since `encoded` is already a string.

Comment: I am sorry its my mistake i apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you're not encrypting but encoding. Encryption typically uses a secret key (or public/private key pair) so that only the person holding the key can decrypt the encrypted message.  Encoding is reversible if you know the algorithm that's used.  Encoding should not be used as a substitute for encryption; it is not secure.

Second, you simply need to reverse the process using the twin of the Convert method you're using to do the encoding.

```
 string decoded = Encoding.Unicode.GetString( Convert.FromBase64String( encoded ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

Base64 isn't "encryption" - it's just a way of representing arbitrary binary data as an entirely ASCII string.

The reverse of `Convert.ToBase64String` is simply [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx), but it's important that you understand that this is *not* an encryption technique. (It's also worth thinking about why you've got that middle line - what do you expect `Convert.ToString` to do when it's passed a string?)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)?

Comment: -1: There's a time and place for snark but it's not "the whole of an answer"

Comment: @Inerdial OP's question track record should almost prove otherwise, but all right, edited.

Answer (score 1):

This code is used to encode/decode string to/from Base64:

```
string inputText = "This is some text.";
byte [] bytesToEncode = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes (inputText);

string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String (bytesToEncode);

byte [] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (encodedText);
string decodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString (decodedBytes);
```